# Scale Azure nginx ingress controller

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

We have a K8s cluster on Azure (aks). On this cluster, we added a loadbalancer on the setup which installed an nginx-ingress controller.

Looking at the deployments:

```
addon-http-application-routing-default-http-backend       1
addon-http-application-routing-external-dns               1 
addon-http-application-routing-nginx-ingress-controller   1
```

I see there is 1 of each running. Now I find very little information if these should be scaled (there is 1 pod each) and if they should, how?

I've tried running

```
kubectl scale deployment addon-http-application-routing-nginx-ingress-controller --replicas=3
```

Which temporarily scales it to 3 pods, but after a few moments, it is downscaled again.

So again, are these supposed to be scaled? Why? How?

**EDIT**

For those that missed it like I did: The AKS addon-http-application is **not** ready for production, it is there to quickly set you up and start experimenting. Which is why I wasn't able to scale it properly.

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/http-application-routing)

Comment: You probably better off installing your own ingress (you can follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls)) and [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/azure.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AKS, being a managed service, this "system" workloads like kube-dns and the ingress controller, are managed by the service itself and they cannot be modified by the user (because they're labeled with `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile`, which forces the current configuration to reflect what's on disk at `/etc/kubernetes/addons` on the masters).

Comment: Does this mean that we do not have to 'care' about it and that aks will handle autoscaling / redundancy etc for it ?

Answer (score 2):

That's generally the way how you do it:

```
$ kubectl scale deployment addon-http-application-routing-nginx-ingress-controller --replicas=3
```

However, I suspect you have an [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) configured which will scale up/down depending on the load or some metrics and has the `minReplicas` spec set to `1`. You can check with:

```
$ kubectl get hpa
$ kubectl describe hpa <hpa-name>
```

If that's the case you can scale up by just patching the HPA:

```
$ kubectl patch hpa <hpa-name> -p '{"spec": {"minReplicas": 3}}'
```

or edit it manually:

```
$ kubectl edit hpa <hpa-name>
```

More information on HPAs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/).

And yes, the ingress controllers are supposed to be scaled up and down depending on the load.

Comment: This should indeed be the way to go, once i've installed a production ready nginx-ingress-controller